# Macvim can not load custom Powerline fonts when started from tmux session

Tags: font, vi, macvim, tmux

I have a really strange issue with MacVim + Tmux + Powerline Fonts.

1. I can run MacVim from the dock or terminal and it correctly starts with Powerline fonts.
2. When I start a tmux session, and launch macvim from tmux, **any custom Font will not load.** If I open the graphical font browser, the font is listed and selected, it just does not modify the font in the UI. If I select another system font, the UI font will change!!

I've tried copying the shell environments between tmux and the standard terminal, but it does not have any affect.

**Does anyone know how tmux could be breaking my fonts in macvim session?**

I'm seeing this issue in Sierra and the exact same [config](http://github.com/cmcginty/dotfiles) works in El Capitan.

Comment: Did you solved this one? I have same problem.

Comment: Yeah, see the answer I posted.

Comment: I tried that package (reattach-to-user-namespace) but still I have same problem. My MacVim don't see powerline fonts and some other stuff. The problem is probably related to env variables but I am not sure how to solve it. Have you tried anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled over the solution with some searching. The issue issue can be fixed with the `reattach-to-user-namespace` tool.

```
$ brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

Add the following line to the end of your `~/.tmux.conf` file

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
```